# PHP Android upload failed

Tags: php, android, upload

I am currently using hosting24.com for php file upload implementation and going to upload mp4 files. The html file for testing , it workds. When it comes to the execution by Android deivces , it fails and shows the $name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"] is null. Would you please tell me is there any other factors preventing us from successful upload  ?

The below is my code

```
public String uploadFIle(File file){
        String result = "";

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;  
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        String fileName =  file.getName();
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        int serverResponseCode = 0;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 

        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            URL url = new URL("http://www.gallicalab.com/upload.php");

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename="
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            if(serverResponseCode==200){
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(    is, "utf-8"), 8192);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                result =   sb.toString();  
            }



        //  result = serverResponseMessage;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }
```

Server side

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $target_path  = "target/";
  //  $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
  //  echo $name."<br>";
    $ext = end(explode(".", $name));
    //    echo $ext."<br>";
    $randname = random_string(30);
   // echo $randname."<br>";
    $fname = $randname . "." .$ext;
    //echo $fname."<br>";
    $target_path = $target_path .$fname;
   // echo $target_path."<br>";
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        //echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name'])." has been uploaded";
        //echo random_string(50);



        // $arr = array ('data'=>'http://gallicalab.com/target/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
        $arr = array ('data'=>'http://gallicalab.com/target/'.$fname);

        echo json_encode($arr); // {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
    } 
    else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }



    function random_string($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return $key;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442021/android-sending-file-to-server-php-receive-that-file-in-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you log what you are actually receiving at the server side to a file? Android app might not be making the request correctly.

Try this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$h = fopen('upload.log', 'w');
fwrite($h, print_r($_POST, true) ."\r\n---\r\n");
fwrite($h, print_r($_FILES, true));
fclose($h);

// rest of your code
```

Then inspect the `upload.log` file and see what happened with your request from device.

---

P.S. Try this alternate upload code for android:

```
private void uploadFile(String filePath, String fileName) {
  InputStream inputStream;
  try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    byte[] data;
    try {
      data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.gallicalab.com/upload.php");

      InputStreamBody inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), fileName);
      MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
      multipartEntity.addPart("file", inputStreamBody);
      httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

      // Handle response back from script.
      if(httpResponse != null) {

      } else { // Error, no response.

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

At server side:

```
$objFile = & $_FILES["file"];
$strPath = basename( $objFile["name"] );

if( move_uploaded_file( $objFile["tmp_name"], $strPath ) ) {
    print "The file " .  $strPath . " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    print "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Source: http://www.codepuppet.com/2013/03/26/android-uploading-a-file-to-a-php-server/

Comment: Array
(
)

---
Array
(
)

It is still empty even using your method

Comment: and I am using hosting24.com

Comment: I have also posted this question ....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162665/android-apache-multipart-php-upload-undefine-index-in-file-line-6#comment31863724_21162665