# php for uploading file called, but file is not stored

Tags: php, android, upload

I am trying to upload a .png file to my server. The php gets called and returns, but the file is never uploaded. I must have some glitch in my code, but I just can't find it.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
if(myBitmap!=null){
    pixels = new byte[myBitmap.getWidth() * myBitmap.getHeight()];
    for (int i = 0; i < myBitmap.getWidth(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myBitmap.getHeight(); ++j) {
            pixels[i + j] = (byte) ((myBitmap.getPixel(i, j) & 0x80) >> 7);
        }
    }
}
HttpURLConnection connectionWWW = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connectionWWW.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);//3.0
connectionWWW.setReadTimeout(100000);
String boundary =  "*****"; 
String attachmentFileName = "screenshot.png";
String crlf = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";

if(imgFile.exists()){
    connectionWWW.setUseCaches(false);//3.0
    connectionWWW.setDoOutput(true);
    connectionWWW.setDoInput(true);
    connectionWWW.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connectionWWW.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

    connectionWWW.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
    connectionWWW.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    connectionWWW.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", attachmentFileName);

    DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(connectionWWW.getOutputStream());

    request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);

    request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\"" + attachmentFileName + "\"" + crlf);
    request.writeBytes(crlf);

    request.write(pixels);

    request.writeBytes(crlf);
    request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);
    request.flush();
    request.close();
}

in = new BufferedInputStream(connectionWWW.getInputStream());

String res = convertStreamToString(in);

connectionWWW.disconnect();//3.0
```

The php:

```
$uploaddir = './android/';
$file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$filet = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
$rec="/android/".$file;
echo $rec;
```

$rec always answers "./android" - $file is empty

Comment: Is there *anything* in `$_FILES`?

Comment: I made a 
var_dump($_FILES);
which shows
file count=0
array(0) {
}

Comment: Are you not using the [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) function? @michaelsmith That is how files are uploaded using PHP. Plus you have a `t` in `$filet` in `$filet = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);` so that could be it. Change it to `$file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);`

Answer (score 2):

Do try the following if you're not already using the [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) function.

That is how files are uploaded using PHP. Plus you have a `t` in `$filet`

```
$filet = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
```

*so that could be it.*

See if this works:

```
$file_path = "./android/"; // assuming running code from root

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {

    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file_path;
    $rec="/android/".$file_path;
    echo $rec;

    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

Also, make sure that the folder has proper write permissions.

**Footnotes:**

I'm unsure of `/android/` and `./android/` one of them may need to be changed in order to reflect the same for each other.

Comment: The php is not the problem. To be absolutely sure, I changed it to your suggestion and I tried with ./android and /android. I also tried on another folder to which uploads work with the iPhone version of the app. All with the same result: the echo is always "fail". The problem must be in the java code, but I have checked and re-checked again and again and can't find what the problem could be. I have also asked our network admin to check if there isn't a firewall rule preventing android to upload files - answer pending

Comment: Hey Michael. Ok, that's why I posted in asking if you were using the `move_uploaded_file()` function. @michaelsmith

Comment: Answer from network admin: No firewall problem, no entry in any logfile.

Comment: More lost than ever on this one

Comment: @michaelsmith: You're facing multiple problems... 1) Your android app is not correctly uploading the file (which is why `var_dump($_FILES)` is showing 0)... and 2) even if it were uploading a file correctly (verified using the `var_dump`), you're not actually *saving* the uploaded file to the server. This is where Fred's answer comes into play as he shows you how to move the TEMP (the "just now uploaded" file) to a KNOWN path (the path you want to save the file). The TEMP file is exactly that... the file that was sent to the server, but stored in a temp directory (usually).

Comment: TBH @michaelsmith I know nothing about Android but my PHP is rather good. If you're running your code from outside the root of your server, you will need to change the path to `$file_path = "../android/";` using `../` depending on how many sub-folders it's going through. If from the `root`, then try `$file_path = "android/";` Have a look at [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21166947/) there's an alternate uploading method for Android.

Comment: @michaelsmith You can also create a PHP file with `<?php phpinfo();?>` inside it and run it from the same place you're running the upload code and it will show you the actual `path` it's using.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it showed that the problem was in the Java code.
I deleted the part with the POST and recreated it, and voilà! it works.
There might have been an invisible stray symbol somewhere in the connection parameters, go figure.

Thanks to anyone for trying to help.

Comment: Right on, always glad to hear a solution was found Michael, cheers and you're welcome. However, did you use that link I provided with the Java code on that page or did you use something else in its place?

Comment: I checked that link. What I did at the end was to retype all the code. If I had more time, I would do a compare to see where the difference is. But the next duty is calling already...